# How to transfer this "Unique" and "Duplicate" excel formula to work in r

Tags: r, excel, database

I have a data set that has duplicate values that are created after the merge of different columns and I can not figure out how to transfer this formula to r.

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B3;B4:$B$10000;0));"Unique";"Duplicate")
```

I have coded this, but it does not work if there are two or more equal dates with equal variables in the original input sheet.

```
test<-mer %>% distinct(time, price.x, volume.x, price.y, volume.y, price, volume, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

I expect to have data like this with the unique filter value at the side. And it would be perfect if anyone could help me out and create such a code that can do this.
**There is an image link down below that shows my goal.** However, there might be 2 exactly the same dates after each other that are not duplicates because something differs in the volume, bid, ask, trade column (as seen in the second picture).

**[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/36MpA.png**
  **[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvjS7.png**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward with `dplyr`, which you already seem to be using.  For example:

```
df %>% 
    group_by_all() %>% 
    mutate(duplicate = ifelse(n() > 1, "Duplicate", "Unique"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the helping (I am kinda new to project R), I think I got the idea, I will keep you updated on what I figure out.  But can I split the big function 'distinct(time, price.x, volume.x, price.y, volume.y, price, volume, .keep_all = TRUE)' into three small ones and then 'cbind' them? But I will try to use your example, you helped a lot !